# SBT: Invalid project ID: Expected ID character when pointing to module in subdirectory

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, multi-project

I a multi-module project structured like this

```
+- multiModuleProject
  +-module1

  +-dir1
    +-subDirModule1
    +-subDirModule2

  +-module3

  +-build.sbt
```

I want both `subDirModule1` and `subDirModule2` to be their own modules outright.

I added something like this to the `build.sbt`

```
lazy val subDir1 = Project(id = "dir1/subDirModule1", base = file("dir1/subDirModule1")
lazy val subDir1 = Project(id = "dir1/subDirModule2", base = file("dir1/subDirModule2")
```

I can't get it to work, I keep getting

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid project ID: Expected ID character
[error] dir1/subDirModule1
[error]     ^
```

But I'm sure I've seen a slash being used in another project I've worked on. What going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Slash is used as a separator between project ID and config and has been for a long time, so I suspect you are misremembering (if you don't, you'd need to escape it all the time and I at least never remember seeing it). You can of course use it in the path (`base` argument), just not in the ID:

```
lazy val subDir1 = Project(id = "subDir1", base = file("dir1/subDirModule1"))
```

and then use e.g.

```
sbt> subDir1/compile
```

You can of course use whatever name you want, but usually the `val` name and the `id` will be the same.